# pybind11: not downcasting to non-polymorphic base class

Tags: c++, pybind11

I'm seeing some odd behavior from `pybind11` when a polymorphic class inherits from a non-polymorphic base class. Consider:

```
struct Base {
    Base() { id = (long int)this; }
    int get_id() const { return id; }
    int get_bthis() const { return (long int)this; }
    long int id;
};
struct Poly: public Base {
    virtual long int polymethod() { return get_id(); }
    long int get_pthis(){ return (long int)this;}
};
```

With the `pybind` of

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    py::class_<Base>(m, "Base")
        .def("get_id", &Base::get_id)
        .def("get_bthis", &Base::get_bthis);
    py::class_<Poly, Base>(m, "Poly")
        .def("get_pthis", &Poly::get_pthis)
        .def("polymethod", &Poly::polymethod);

    m.def("make_base",[]() { return new Base();});
    m.def("make_poly",[]() { return new Poly();});
}
```

It appears the Poly->Base pointer is not upcast in the trampoline because `example.make_poly().get_id()` returns garbage; the `this` pointer is not properly offset by the vtable:

```
>>> import example
>>> base = example.make_base()
>>> base.get_id() # Ok
7038096
>>> base.get_bthis() # Ok
7038096
>>> poly = example.make_poly()
>>> poly.get_pthis() # Ok
7046720
>>> virt.polymethod() # Ok
7046728
>>> poly.get_bthis() # BUGGY, get_bthis() should be same as polymethod()
7046720
>>> poly.get_id() # BUGGY, but can crash!
-1116853264
```

The equivalent in native C++ properly considers the base class offset:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    auto base = new Base();
    std::cout << "base->get_this():" << base->get_this() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "base->get_id():" << base->get_id() << std::endl;

    auto virt = new Poly();
    std::cout << "poly->get_bthis():" << poly->get_bthis() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "poly->get_id():" << poly->get_id() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "poly->get_pthis():" << poly->get_pthis() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "poly->polymethod():" << poly->polymethod() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
base->get_bthis():14856208
base->get_id():14856208

poly->get_bthis():14856248
poly->get_id():14856248
poly->get_pthis():14856240
poly->polymethod():14856248
```

I'm most suspicious of `py::class_<Poly, Base>(m, "Poly")`, but without it I cannot use `Poly::get_id`. Is this a pybind bug, or am I not declaring my class inheritance correctly? Making `Base` also polymorphic (say by adding `virtual ~Base()`) makes everything work.

Or is this ultimately down to static dispatch vs dynamic dispatch; the latter which "requires" polymorphic base classes in C++?

Edited: a previous version of this question referred to a "virtual class"  instead of the correct term of "polymorphic class".

Comment: Classes aren’t virtual or not—they’re *polymorphic* or not.  This matters because “virtual base class” means virtual inheritance (`struct A : virtual B {};`).

Comment: Thanks @DavisHerring you're right! Though it appears "virtual class" has some meaning (though definitely not the usage I intended): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_class

Comment: Interesting.  I’ve never heard anyone use that term (with that meaning), but I can see how it might be interesting—at least in languages like Python where every lookup can be “virtual”.  C++ and Java don’t do that, though—only functions can be virtual—so I wonder why the Wikipedia example uses C++.